# CURL "failed to open stream: Redirection limit reached" works local but not on server

Tags: php, curl

I have a script that works on my local machine, on a shared server, on web browser, **but not on VPS**.

I use CURL to download a webpage's HTML, for example this url:

```
https://www.yes.co.il/content/YesChannelsHandler.ashx?action=GetDailyShowsByDayAndChannelCode&dayValue=0&dayPartByHalfHour=37&channelCode=YSAL
```

It fails with an error:

```
failed to open stream: Redirection limit reached
```

The VPS php version is: *PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.3*

Any ideas how to solve this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your VPS has a different max redirection limit then the other environments. You should be able to increase it using the cUrl PHP option CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS.

Assuming you are using the resource name $ch:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it's still not working. I have even tried with a higher number then 10.

Answer (score 0):

Your version works locally, but not on the server. And, it seems that you are accessing https://. So, try with:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

Also, find out how many redirection are happening, and if possible, give the last URL in the redirect.

Answer (score 0):

What about follow location setting? Did you try?

Comment: CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION set to true, http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php